# Not able to read InputStream from RS232 Bluetooth module

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port

I am trying to read values from a weighing machine connected to bluetooth module([M143 RS232 Bluetooth Serial Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1lx4.jpg) purchased from [eBay](http://www.ebay.in/itm/RS232-Bluetooth-Serial-Adapter-Master-Slave-Module-5v-Mini-USB-KG531-/122524578483?hash=item1c8708b2b3:g:djwAAOSwH09ZLm6~)).I am able to connect the device and i am getting `Socket` object.But the `InputStream` is blocking and not able to read data from the stream(`inputstream.available()` is always returns zero).There is no issue when i write something to the `OutputStream`.I tried using BufferedReader but no change.Following is the code i tried.

```
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
   total.append(line).append('\n');
}
//code is not reaching here it is blocking in the while loop
if(outputStream!=null){
  outputStream.flush();
  outputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Maybe your device isn't sending a "line". What is to try to read a single byte with `r.read()` ? Maybe something special in the device protocol ...

Comment: I tried r.read() also,but same thing is happening

Comment: @[PeterMmm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114226/petermmm)  why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe because the device is not sending any data ?

Comment: I tried by connecting [RS232 to USB converter](http://www.amazon.in/Black-RS-232-Serial-Converter-Adapter/dp/B01I1ZP17C/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1498622970&sr=8-2&keywords=rs232+to+usb+converter) to connect weighing machine to PC and by using [RS232 Data Logger](https://www.eltima.com/products/rs232-data-logger/) software it is printing the values of weighing machine correctly.

Comment: So probably the Andoid interface isn't working as expected. Maybe you can test serial com on the target Android system (https://felhr85.net/2015/01/09/a-dirty-and-quick-example-of-serial-port-communication-in-android/). I'm out of clue.

Comment: If you want be sure bt device works you can download a Bluetooth Terminal like program for pc. If you display data in pc, then check each step for connection starting AcceptThread or Connected thread, i use log to see connection is estashlished. If connection is established, check connected thread and inputStream for available bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you opening sockets for connection in different threads. There should be 3 threads for connection. This is valid for non-Bluetooth LE. [Bluetooth Connectitivty](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

1. Connection Thread
2. Accept Thread
3. Connected Thread

If you use these threads, you will be able to get data using connected thread and you can pass data to main thread using handler, callback or BroadcastReceiver. I use all three of them seamlessly.

If you wish to check whether it works or not, download Bluetooth Terminal app from Play Store. It exactly uses Threads and Handler to display data. You can find one of the Bluetooth Terminal source code too. One of them is open source.

For BLE you can try this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html). There are working samples associated with guides.
If you want to be sure your BT device works, download a BT terminal program pc or/and Android and test your device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Still not displaying weight,is there any command to display data?

Comment: When doe it not display? When using threads or using Bluetooth Terminal app?

Comment: You should check your device then. All apps on the market use the almost same code provided by Google to get data.

Open sockets in threads and open an inputstream and use a handler to get and display data.

If you use Bluetooth Terminal or messaging app on Google's page and try it on 2 devices you will see that both of them works. You may need to send a message maybe to start your device to send data. In our project we send 3 digit messages to start buzzing or stop buzzing a bluetooth device.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that .read() or .readline() only halts reading when there is a newline or EOF, end of file.

However, socket connection does not have EOF unless the socket transfer is done.

so you could do the two following cases:

1) Change the other side(weighing machine in your case) to add \n or \r after each data transfer to let the Android side know one full set of data was sent.
This keeps the benefit of socket connection.
and you could do

```
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    //do what you want to do with line
    //... you dont need string builder in this case
}
```

2) Halt each connection from the other side after each data transfer. This is not recommended because it is not anymore a socket transfer when you cut after every data transfer. Also it might cause TIME_WAIT and hinder further connections.

I was able to do the first case to solve my problem when I was in your shoes.

Answer (score 1):

The execution blocking in reading of `InputStream` is because of if no bytes are coming from the `Socket`,the existing thread will wait for a byte to come from the `Socket`.

Comment: Even if there were bytes coming from the socket, your code when using readline() will be blocked after reading those bytes because of what I said.

Answer (score 1):

Communication via bluetooth with other android devices or microcontrollers such as Arduino [Android Smooth Bluetooth](https://github.com/palaima/AndroidSmoothBluetooth)

// This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.

// It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }
```